# PHP Session Only Works On Some Pages

Tags: php, ajax, session

this is kinda weird. Ok so I'm working with a session to know when the user has logged in. When the user logs in a session gets created.

The problem i'm having is the session isn't working on some pages. When I do a `var_dump($_SESSION['u_up']);` on my index page it show the session: `array(1) { ["u_up"]=> string(7) "example" }` but when I make an Ajax call to another script and do the same `var_dump($_SESSION['u_up']);` it returns an empty array: `array(0){}`.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have `session_start()` on top on both files but somehow my second script won't pick up on my sessions. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is my simple Ajax script:

```
//Update to not view tutorial           
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://192.168.1.75/php/script.php',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does both of your pages are on the same domain / sub domain?

Comment: The code you show is just not enough to figure out solutions, add the ajax script and the essential part of the php script which is not working

Comment: please make sure your `php.ini` file does have this :`session.use_cookies = 1` and path is set for `session_save`

Comment: Ok I added my Ajax script, and yes both scripts are on my local environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out I had to change the `url` in the Ajax request to localhost. So it ended up looking like this:

```
//Update to not view tutorial           
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/php/script.php',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Don't really know why i have to specify `localhost` instead of being able to specify my computer's ip.

Comment: [Difference between 127.0.0.1 and IPv4 address](https://superuser.com/questions/897699/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-my-assigned-ipv4-address)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a cross domain request, **192.168.1.75** and **localhost** are not considered the same domains and do not share cookies.

For safety reasons cross domain requests does not include cookies. If you don't send the phpsessid cookie you won't be able to retrieve your old php session, which will make your session empty.

Beside this i strongly suggest you to use relative path to avoir such issues in the futur.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/php/script.php',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```